# Datetime.toString() no funciona. C#

Tags: c#, datetime, xamarin.android

Realizo un código dónde tengo una fecha en string y la transformo a DateTime y luego nuevamente a un string, pero le doy un formato específico de fecha ("dd/MM/yyyy") ya que el usuario puede tener un formato de fecha diferente al que necesito dentro del dispositivo.

El problema es que un usuario tiene el formato dd.MM.yyyy y cuando quiero pasaron al formato  dd/MM/yyyy se queda en la variable con dd.MM.yyyy. Este inconveniente pasa solo cuando quiero cambiar a este tipo de fomrato dd/MM/yyyy ya que probé poner este formato dd-MM-yyyy y sí funcionó, no sé a que se debe ese inconveniente.

También traté de usar CultureInfo dentro del método Parse y no funcionó.

El código es el siguiente:

```
private string GetRecoveryDate()
    {
        string date = string.Empty;
        DateTime temp;

        switch (SelectedDay)
        {
            case "M":
                temp = DateTime.Parse(LunesDateFormat);
                date = temp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                break;

            case "T":
                temp = DateTime.Parse(MartesDateFormat);
                date = temp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                break;

            case "W":
                temp = DateTime.Parse(MiercolesDateFormat);
                date = temp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                break;

            case "R":
                temp = DateTime.Parse(JuevesDateFormat);
                date = temp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                break;

            case "F":
                temp = DateTime.Parse(ViernesDateFormat);
                date = temp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                break;

            case "S":
                temp = DateTime.Parse(SabadoDateFormat);
                date = temp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                break;

            case "U":
                temp = DateTime.Parse(DomingoDateFormat);
                date = temp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                break;
        }

        return date;
    }
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: dd.MM.yyyy no es una estructura valida para las fechas, por lo que el Parse no te lo transformará a Datetime. Deberás hacer un replace primero SabadoDateFormat.replace(".","-")

Comment: Según esta documentación este formato es válido de-DE Culture                               31.10.2008. https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-6.0#code-try-2

Answer (score 2):

Cuando el formato de fecha a parsear no es "estandar", .net no puede saber exactamente como interpretar la cadena de entrada. Para esos casos, se dispone del método [ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0) donde puedes indicarle cual es el formato de la cadena de entrada.

En tu caso, puedes hacer algo como en este ejemplo:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var fecha= DateTime.ParseExact("10.05.2022","dd.MM.yyyy",provider).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    
Console.WriteLine(fecha); //devuelve 10/05/2022
```

Comment: Tengo una duda, sin embargo el usuario puede tener diferntes formatos no necesariamente dd.MM.yyyy y el parseExact no funcionaría en esos casos. Otra cosa que agregar es que en un proyecto diferente el método parse de la manera en que uso en este ejemplo si funciona, no sé si es algo de xamarin.

Comment: @KeruDavid si hay posibilidad de que los formatos sean diferentes, la solución es dificil la verdad. Podrías probar con `TryParseExact` hasta dar con una que sea valida, pero habría posibilidad de falsas conversiones. Por ejemplo..`01/10/2020` podria ser 1 de octubre si el formato es europeo, o 10 de enero si es americano. En cuanto a lo de xamarin..no te se decir, nunca he programado en eso.